Unity 3d Interaction System Glitching
So in this unity project I have created a interaction to glorify that which counter I am currently facing so depending on that I can spawn related items from it but the game object should only Console "Selected" if I am looking towards it only but it's happening Even if I am not looking towards it or is far away from it after first enabling it, it even sometimes becomes disabled when I face the counter again which is totally against the script I just wrote So any kind of help will be much appreciated.
Interactions Function
private void HandleInteractions()
{
    Vector2 inputVector = gameInput.GameMovementVectorNormalized();

    //This Transform relates to the actual transfor of the Project Asset aur in this case Player
    Vector3 movDir = new Vector3(inputVector.x, 0f, inputVector.y);

    if (movDir != Vector3.zero)
    {
        lastInteractDir = movDir;
    }

    float interactDistance = 1f;

    //This method will detect collision and will return the collision objects reference too for interaction purposes
    //Here we used the lastInteractDir to even if if stopped moving towards and interactable object
    //we still get that objects reference to use it
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, lastInteractDir, out RaycastHit raycastHit, interactDistance, countersLayerMask))
    {
        if (raycastHit.transform.TryGetComponent(out ClearCounter clearCounter))
        {
            //Has Clear Counter
            //clearCounter.Interact();
            if (clearCounter != selectedCounter)
            {
                SetSelectedCounter(clearCounter);
                //Here
            }
            else
            {
                //something in front but doesn't has clear counter script
                SetSelectedCounter(null);
                //Here
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //if nothing infront
            SetSelectedCounter(null);
            //Here
        }

    }
    //can use RaycastAll() to cycle through many possible objects to get interactions
    //or can use the Raycast(15) to use the layers mask method and handle interactions
    //based on Layers
}

Invoke Function
private void SetSelectedCounter(ClearCounter selectedCounter)
{
    //this funtion so we dont have to duplicate code again and agian in the usage areas
    this.selectedCounter = selectedCounter;

    onSelectedCounterChanged?.Invoke(this, new onSelectedCounterChangedEventArgs
    {
        //making cross interaction between for selected counter and Clear counter per say
        selectedCounter = selectedCounter
    });
}

Event
    public event EventHandler<onSelectedCounterChangedEventArgs> onSelectedCounterChanged;
    public class onSelectedCounterChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        //This is the proper convention for Event Creation
        public ClearCounter selectedCounter;
    }

Interaction Function
private void GameInput_OnInteractAction(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (selectedCounter != null)
        {
            //if counterinfront is not null then Interation can be made
            selectedCounter.Interact();
        }
    }



Activity Handler
private void Start()
{
    Player.Instance.onSelectedCounterChanged += Player_onSelectedCounterChanged;
}

private void Player_onSelectedCounterChanged(object sender, Player.onSelectedCounterChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.selectedCounter == clearCounter)
    {
        Show();
    }
    else
    {
        Hide();
    }
}

private void Show()
{
    visualGameObject.SetActive(true);
}

private void Hide()
{
    visualGameObject.SetActive(false);
}

Interact Function Logging
public void Interact()
    {
        Debug.Log("Interact!");
    }



Thanks a bunch!

Is the direction you look fixed to the movement direction?

nope it wasn't turns out that I misplaced a conditioning transition that decides where to look at I fixed it, thanks for the response by the way.
